# Is it possible to create a branch automatically from a jira issue without using any 3rd party softwares

Tags: git, github, jira, github-actions, jira-agile

Whenever the issue is created in jira and the work is in progress is it possible to have a branch created in GitHub automatically, without us manually having to create a branch with the issue number? Can it be done without any 3rd party apps?

Comment: Git knows nothing about Jira, and Jira is Atlassian/Bitbucket so is a rival for GitHub. You might consider using Bitbucket instead of GItHub: since Jira is their own product they're much more likely to have it integrated.

Comment: If you cannot find anything in JIRA documentation, then third party software is required. Questions that ask about possibility are often voted to be closed, as not much to be discussed.